# ERROR bad URI `keep-alive'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, uri

I often receive the following error in my console. I searched for the solution am not able to find the solution.

```
 Completed 200 OK in 201ms (Views: 197.1ms | ActiveRecord: 2.1ms)
    [2015-07-21 10:47:48] ERROR bad URI `keep-alive'.
    [2015-07-21 10:47:48] ERROR bad URI `keep-alive'.    
    [2015-07-21 10:47:48] ERROR bad URI `keep-alive'.
```

And error in screen was:

```
Length Required
WEBrick::HTTPStatus::LengthRequired
WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.2.1/2015-02-26) at localhost:3000
```

Comment: We need more context, information, code and stacktrace

Comment: It looks like a `URI` is not getting parsed properly, particularly with the `keep-alive` field.